# replace current html image with css

Tags: html, css

I am having issues trying to replace this image with CSS, I have no access to the html.

http://jsfiddle.net/ES4mH/

```
<img 
  width="64" 
  height="64" 
  border="0" 
  style="width: 64px; height: 64px;" 
  src="http://www.nitrografixx.com/2013/lock-icon.gif">
</img>
```

I tried this, and while it adds the image as a background to the current image, it doesn't replace it.

```
img[src='http://www.nitrografixx.com/2013/lock-icon.gif'] {
  background: url(http://www.nitrografixx.com/2013/lock_bg.jpg) center !important;  
}
```

Comment: Instead of background property, use content property.

Comment: Your code it's working properly. You are 'saying' to CSS that when he finds an `img` element with attribute `src` with that given url as his attribute value, then change the background image of your `img` element into the one you written at his `background` property on CSS. You have to change `background` property into `content`

Comment: If you have Javascript, you'll be better off using that instead of CSS, because you can simply directly access the image and change it, instead of trying to apply a `content` attribute via CSS.

Comment: Img tags are self containing tags you dont need a closing tag.

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
<style>
.className{
    content:url("http://www.nitrografixx.com/2013/lock_bg.jpg");
}
</style>
<img class="className"/>
```

Comment: As the OP has no access to the HTML, you'd need to change `.className` to `img[src='http://www.nitrografixx.com/2013/lock-icon.gif']`?

Comment: This is definitely the way to go… in CSS (so: good answer to the question as asked). But Javascript would be a much better way of handling the issue.

Comment: Also, the URL you've used is the one that was there already, he'd want the `content: url("http://www.nitrografixx.com/2013/lock_bg.jpg");` I think.

Comment: adding the content, did not replace the image either, any more ideas ?

Comment: It will depend upon the browser you are using, it works in the latest Chrome, but not IE10. I see a pink image instead of the lock. http://jsfiddle.net/ES4mH/47/

Comment: ok i see it working in Chrome, but not IE10,FF21 or safari ... so guess i won't use...thanks

Comment: WOW, whats going on here i thaught `content` was for pseudo elements?

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is adding the image to the background of the image element but the image element still has the source attribute pointing to the original image and that's why it's not being removed. You should probably use javscript to remove the element and replace it with something else if that's possible.

Comment: i do not have access to the html and can not add an java to the site, i can only alter existing css

Comment: @user2250423 Java is not javascript. Javascript is available in virtually all browsers.